# $P(\min(x,y) \ge k) = P(x \ge k, y \ge k)$?

Tags: probability

I want to find the $\text{CDF}$ of $V = \min(X, Y)$ given $X$ and $Y$ are geometric random variables and are independent. We want to calculate $P(V \leq k)$, so why do we go and do $P(\min(X,Y) \ge k) = P(X \ge k, Y \ge k) = P(X \ge k) P(Y \ge k)$, what is the logic of this?

Comment: Do you agree that "$\min(X,Y)\geq k$" is exactly the same statement as "$X\geq k$ and $Y\geq k$"?

Comment: Your title (body) asks about $P(\min(X,\,Y)\le k)$ ($P(\min(X,\,Y)\ge k)$).

Comment: I modified my quesiton.

Comment: Right.   $\min (X,Y) \ge k \iff X\ge k$ AND $Y\ge k$.  And if $A$ and $B$ are independent events $P(A$ and $B) = P(A)\cdot P(B)$ and there really isn't anything more to say.

Comment: my question is why for cdf we want to calculate $P(V \leq k)$ and we do $P(V \ge k)$

Comment: Well we should actually calculate $P(V > k)$ (strictly greater) We do that because $$P(V\le k) = 1 - P(\lnot V \le k ) = 1-P(V>k)=1-P(\min(X,Y) > k) = 1- P(X> k\text{ and }Y>k)= 1-P(X>k)\cdot P(Y>k)$$.    It's easier to figure out the probability of both values being something than to figure out the probability of one or the other being something.

Comment: $P(A$ and $B) = P(A)P(B)$.   But $P(N$ or $B)$ is not so direct.  The easiest way is $P(N$ or $B) = 1-P($neither $N$ nor $B)=1-P($not $A)\cdot P($not $B)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\rhd$ This is because the events $(\min(X,Y) \geq k)$ and $(X \geq k) \cap (Y \geq k)$ are equal. Indeed :

- If $\min(X,Y) \geq k$, then as $X \geq \min(X,Y) $ and $Y \geq \min(X,Y)$, we get $X \geq k$ and $Y \geq k$.
- If $X \geq k$ and $Y \geq k$, then $\min(X,Y)$ is either equal to $X$ or $Y$ (depending on the values taken by $X$ and $Y$), and as both of them are greater than $k$, we necessarily have : $\min(X,Y) \geq k$.

We therefore get $P(\min(X,Y) \geq k) = P((X \geq k) \cap (Y \geq k))$, and as $X$ and $Y$ are independent :
$$P(\min(X,Y) \geq k) = P(X \geq k) \times P(Y \geq k).$$

$\rhd$ We can then find the distribution of $\min(X,Y)$ by noting that the event $(\min(X,Y)=k)$ is the same as^$(\min(X,Y)\geq k) \setminus (\min(X,Y)\geq k+1)$. We then get :
$$P(\min(X,Y) = k)=P(\min(X,Y) \geq k)-P(\min(X,Y) \geq k+1)$$
and the previous computation allows us to fin the value of $P(\min(X,Y) = k)$.

Comment: I didn't ask about this.

Comment: I edited my answer to explain how to use the result